# SWIFT - How to get Stream for Server

Tags: swift, cfstream

On client we can use CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost to get ReadStream and WriteStream.

After the server got clientSocket how can we got ReadStream and WriteStreaam?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking, but this documentation might help: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NetworkingTopics/Articles/UsingSocketsandSocketStreams.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/CH73-SW8

Answer (score 3):

```
import UIKit

class Connection: NSObject, NSStreamDelegate {
    var inputStream: NSInputStream!
    var outputStream: NSOutputStream!

    func connect() {
        var readStream:  Unmanaged<CFReadStream>?
        var writeStream: Unmanaged<CFWriteStream>?

        CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(nil, "193.10.1.22", 17, &readStream, &writeStream)

        self.inputStream = readStream!.takeRetainedValue()
        self.outputStream = writeStream!.takeRetainedValue()

        self.inputStream.delegate = self
        self.outputStream.delegate = self

        self.inputStream.scheduleInRunLoop(NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop(), forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)
        self.outputStream.scheduleInRunLoop(NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop(), forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)

        self.inputStream.open()
        self.outputStream.open()
    }
}
```